# php how to extract text from between quotes and exclude quotes

Tags: string, extract, quotes

This is the string

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Resurrection Power+ Part 2 (El 
Poder de la Resurrección) 20-3-2022.mp3"
```

I want to extract this

Resurrection Power+ Part 2 (El Poder de la Resurrección) 20-3-2022.mp3

Comment: I think a regex could be useful...

Comment: Something like `filename="(?<filename>.*)"`, just an idea...

Comment: Not sure how you would apply that, could you elaborate ?

Comment: The part of the line I need is the phrase which will always begin after the word 'filename="' and end including the '.mp3"' minus the single quotes e.g. filename=" and .mp3"